# Scala -- not a member of package

Tags: scala

I am learning Scala so bear with me if this is a stupid question.

I have this package and a class (teared it down to most simplistic version):

```
package Foo {
  class Bar {}
}
```

then in `main.scala` file I have:

```
import Foo.Bar

object test {
  def main() {
    val b = new Bar()
  }
}
```

Why am I getting this:

> test.scala:1: error: Bar is not a member of Foo

It points at the `import` statement.

Comment: How are you compiling this? Are you using sbt or maven or something that understands package structure?

Comment: The `scala` command doesn't compile a program, it runs one.  I would suggest looking into `sbt` or, if it's a really simple application, just putting everything in one file.

Comment: Is there a way to do this handily in Intellij IDEA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quickly test a scala code in IntelliJ (with the [Scala plugin](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/SCA/Scala+Plugin+for+IntelliJ+IDEA)), you can simply type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>:

[image: test code in Scala]

Note that for testing a Scala class, you have other choices, also supported in IntelliJ:

- [JUnit or TestNG](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/SCA/Testing+Frameworks+Support)
- [ScalaTest](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/SCA/ScalaTest+Support)

Comment: I don't have the keyboard shortcut -- are you referring to running "Scala Console"? Btw, I didn't down vote.

Comment: @rFactor You need to have the Scala plugin installed in your IntelliJ, for that feature to be available. And it is only for interpreted a few lines of Scala, which might not be exactly what you want to do.

Comment: I have the plugin installed and configured and I can run "Scala Console" in which case it just opens the Scala REPL... what keyboard shortcut are you referring to?

Comment: Ok I changed my keyboard set back to defaults and I can now use it.

Comment: @rFactor glad you made it work (I just got back from work and only saw your message now)

Answer (score 3):

`scalac` is the scala compiler. `Foo.bar` needs to have been compiled for you to use it, so you can't just run your main.scala as a script.

The other mistake in your code is that the `main` method needs to be

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {  ...
```

(or you could have `test extends App` instead and do away with the `main` method).

I can confirm if you put the two files above in an empty directory (with the correction on the main method signature) and run `scalac *` followed by `scala test` it runs correctly.

Comment: I get `error: source file 'Foo' could not be found` for running `scalac *` alone.

Comment: @rFactor note I said "in an empty directory". If you have other files in there as well you need to direct it specifically at the *.scala files

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that you did not compile the first file, or you are doing something wrong when compiling. Let's say both files are in the current directory, then this should work:

```
scalac *.scala
```

It should generate some class files in the current directory, as well as a `Bar.class` file in the `Foo` directory, which it will create.

Comment: I get `error: source file 'Foo' could not be found` for running `scalac *` alone.

Comment: Is there a sensible way to re-compile every file that has changed and then run the single file I want using something like Intellij IDEA?

Comment: @rFactor That was `scalac *.scala` -- you don't want to pass non-scala files to it. As for IDEA, I assume if you clean the project that's what will happen.